# Resizable div Css / JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, resizable

Hi How can I create a resizable div?

```
<div id="main">

</div>
```

---

```
#main {
    width: 100 px;
    box-shadow: #254C58 1px 0px;
    border: #3C7D91 5 px double;
    padding: 10 px 10 px 10 px 10 px;
    overflow - y: scroll;
    max-height: 433 px;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').resizable();

});
```

Here is my jsfiddle to my question:

This is a example but it doesn't work:  https://jsfiddle.net/tetut91e/2/

Can someone help me?

Comment: i think you need to use both js and css file.
https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is what you looking for

```
resize: both;
```

here is working code: https://jsfiddle.net/tetut91e/5/

Comment: Your example is cool, but it doesn't work at my code my div is filled with dc.js charts but isn't it the same ? no matter what is in the div or?

Answer (score 4):

U need to add jquery-ui.js

```
<div id="main"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#main" ).resizable();
});
```

I updated your jsfiddle code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tetut91e/4/)

Answer (score 1):

In your Fiddle you have not defined jQuery and jQuery UI as dependecies and also tere is some problems with your css (i.e.: replace `10 px` with `10px`)

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tetut91e/2/)

```
#main {
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: #254C58 1px 0px;
    border: #3C7D91 5 px double;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow - y: scroll;
    max-height: 433 px;
    background:#f00;
    min-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code some external js and css were missing and there were also mistakes in the css. Please find below working code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></style>

<style>
    #main {
        width: 100 px;
        box-shadow: #254C58 1px 0px;
        border: #3C7D91 5px double;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        overflow - y: scroll;
        max-height: 433px;
    }
</style>
<div id="main">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main').draggable();
        $('#main').resizable();

    });
</script>
```